# Bad c++ code design?

Tags: object-oriented, c++, coding-style, performance, code-quality

This is bothering me a long time. I feel like I am doing mistakes on the code design relative to the performance. I never had any teacher to indicate my mistakes so its hard to me to make it right in practice.

The code is about a server I am creating. I divided the program in some main classes like the "Receiver", "Sender, "Data_Handler", "Socket"... (because i thought it was more organized).
I use dynamic memory allocation to create them on the `main.cpp` (What should be bad for performance...?).
Then I pass those classes by pointers to the others classes to use its functions and variables I need.
Should i make them static classes? 
Where do I need to change about my code method?

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "UserData.h"
#include "DataHandler.h"
#include "Sender.h"
#include "Socket.h"
#include "Receiver.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    bool State = true;

    Socket *socket = new Socket;
    UserData *userdata = new UserData(socket);
    Receiver *receiver = new Receiver(socket, userdata);
    DataHandler *datahandler = new DataHandler(socket, userdata, receiver);
    Sender *sender = new Sender(socket, userdata, datahandler);

    while (State)
    {
        /* - - - - - - - - -Receive Data- - - - - - - - - - - */
        int Activity = SDLNet_CheckSockets(socket->Socket_Set, 0);
        if (Activity > 0)
        {
            /*      ---    Accept     ---    */
            while (SDLNet_SocketReady(socket->s_tcp))
            {
                --Activity;
                userdata->Accept();
                if (userdata->Who == Max_Users)userdata->Data_Status = 3;
                datahandler->TCP_Handler();
                sender->Send();
                if (userdata->Data_Status == 3)userdata->disconnect();

            }
            /*       ---     UDP      ---     */
            while (SDLNet_SocketReady(socket->s_udp))
            {
                --Activity;
                receiver->udp();
                datahandler->UDP_Handler();
                sender->Send();
            }
            /*     ---    TCP     ---    */
            unsigned int i = 0;
            while (Activity)
            {
                if (userdata->Check_TCP(i))
                {
                    --Activity;

                    //Data Flow
                    receiver->tcp();
                    datahandler->TCP_Handler();
                    sender->Send();

                    //Disconnect User
                    if (userdata->Data_Status){ i--; userdata->disconnect(); }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    delete receiver;
    delete sender;
    delete datahandler;
    delete userdata;
    delete socket;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**DataHandler.h** (one random class)

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Socket.h"
#include "UserData.h"
#include "Receiver.h"
#include "Constants.h"



class DataHandler
{
public:
    DataHandler::DataHandler(Socket *socket_p, UserData *userdata_p, Receiver *receiver_p);
    void UDP_Handler();
    void TCP_Handler();
    DataHandler::~DataHandler();

    int For;
    bool How;
    std::string What;

private:
    Socket *socket;
    UserData *userdata;
    Receiver *receiver;

    std::string data_part;
    std::istringstream divider;

    //TCP
    void Accepted();
    void Full();
    void Disconnected();
    void Login();

    //UDP
    void Confirm();
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with this pattern. I use it myself in a few places.

The only thing I'd really suggest is getting rid of the dynamic allocations, not because they're going to have *any* noticeable performance effect in your case but because it's an unnecessary mess that you have to remember to clean up at the end. You can still use pointers without the dynamic allocation:

```
Socket socket;
UserData userdata(&socket);
Receiver receiver(&socket, &userdata);
DataHandler datahandler(&socket, &userdata, &receiver);
Sender sender(&socket, &userdata, &datahandler);
```

It might be neater to use references than pointers, though.

As your application grows, you may consider using a "registry" to store these components that can be accessed and used by their friends.

Just watch out for circular dependencies. And it's a concern to me that you pass the same pointers into multiple components. Can you make your design "layered" so that you don't need to pass the `Socket` instance into *all* your other objects? It seems like the `UserData` and `Receiver` ought to be handling all interactions with the `Socket`, and that the `DataHandler` shouldn't be able to mess anything up by interacting with the `Socket`.